# calculate vector after rotating it towards another by angle θ in 3D space

Tags: math, vector

[image]

Unit vectors V and D lie on a 3D space. They have the same starting point. I want to rotate the vector V towards to vector D, but only by angle θ.

Given that we know:

1. Vectors V and D are unit vectors.
2. We know V(x,y,z) and D(x,y,z).
3. We know the angle between the two vectors V and D, Δφ.
4. We also know the angle θ, where the vector V will rotate to approach vector D.
5. We know the starting point "O" where the three vectors start from.

We now want to calculate vector Z, which will also be a unit vector.
Is it possible to calculate the coordinates of vector Z, with this information given above?

Do you have any ideas how this problem can be solved?

Comment: A minor quibble: with vectors, there is no "starting point," so that is not relevant. Maybe you were thinking of a line segment, which does have both a start and an end points.

Comment: Besides the solution proposed by @comingstorm, another option is to use [quaternions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation), specially if you want to apply the same rotation to more than one vector.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you need to do is to define a third axis in the plane of the V and D vectors such that a 90 degree rotation from V points in this direction. I'll call the unit vector that points in this direction D'. With this, your Z vector is easy:

```
Z = cos(theta)*V + sin(theta)*D_tick;
```

So how to compute D'? That, too is easy. First compute a vector orthogonal to V and D using the cross product. Call this W: W = V×D. Next compute a vector orthogonal to W and V: D' = W×V = (V×D)×V. This points in the right direction, but it will only be a unit vector if your V and D are orthogonal. So normalize: D' = D'/||D'||, where ||D'|| is the magnitude of the vector D'. If you have a vector math package, you can do this via

```
D_tick = ((V.cross(D)).cross(V)).normalize();
```

One caveat: What if ||D'|| is zero? That happens if and only if your Δφ is a multiple of pi radians (or 180 degrees). Alternatively, it happens when V and D are parallel or anti-parallel to one another. Your question is ill posed in this special case. You should check for this special case.

---

**Addendum**
My (V×D)×V and comingstorm's D - V*((D·V)/(V·V)) are one and the same for vectors in three dimensional space. Because V is a unit vector, his D-V*((D·V)/(V·V)) reduces to D-V(D·V). My (V×D)×V is equal to D(V·V)-V(D·V) per the vector triple product identity (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VectorTripleProduct.html), and this reduces to D-V(D·V), again because V is a unit vector.

Comment: You need to scale `D_tick` by `length(V)` to get a correct rotation, I think.

Comment: @comingstorm - Length(V) is one, by definition. V is a unit vector.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a silly question. But when I calculate Z, you mean:


Zx = cos(theta) * Vx + sin(theta) * D'x 
Zy = ......

Comment: Exactly. The most basic definition of what constitutes a 'vector' includes addition of two vectors and multiplication by a scalar. For the vectors you are concerned with, multiplying by a scalar means multiplying each component by that scalar, and adding two vectors means adding them component-wise.

Answer (score 6):

One way to do this is to find the component of `D` perpendicular to `V`, scale it up to equivalent length, and do a vector sum using `sin()` and `cos()`:

```
D_perp = D - V * ((D . V)/(V . V))

D_perp_scaled = D_perp * (|V|/|D_perp|)

result = cos(theta) * V + sin(theta) * D_perp_scaled
```

This is well-defined unless `D` is parallel to `V`, which will make `|D_perp| == 0` and cause problems with the division.  This isn't really surprising:  in that case your plane of rotation is ill-defined -- it isn't clear which direction you should rotate!

Mathematically, this method for finding the perpendicular is equivalent to the cross-product method `cross(cross(V,D),V)` mentioned in other answers, but is perhaps a bit simpler, and works for any vector space, (e.g., 2-D and 4-D vectors, not just 3-D).

Answer (score 1):

The vector **Q** is given by the [cross product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) **V** × **D**.  The cross product of two 3D vectors is always perpendicular to the the two arguments of the cross product.  So that will be the axis of rotation.  In your case, **Q** will be given by:

```
Qx = VyDz - VzDy
Qy = VzDx - VxDz
Qz = VxDy - VyDx
```

Note that **V** × **D** = -**D** × **V** so there may be a sign issue.  Also, **Q** will in general not be a unit vector which is often required for rotation, so be sure to divide it by its magnitude and use **Q**' = **Q**/|**Q**| (**Q** ≠ 0) before using it as the axis of rotation.

Comment: Thanks!! this seems really helpful, but Z in my case, Z is the vector I want to rotate around the perpendicular! Let's call the perpendicular Q. After that I should rotate the vector V around Q by angle θ, is that right?

Comment: Okay... I couldn't see your picture originally; I've updated to reflect this.  And yes, that's right.

Comment: Thanks a lot! you have no idea how relieved I feel right now!